# How to change the background of a grouped tableview cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to change the background of a grouped table view cell.  Say you have 5 grouped cell.  The top cell is rounded corner at the top left and right corners and the bottom cell is rounded at the bottom left and right corners, and the middle cells have no rounded corners. this is where the problem is. if I setbackground of each cell, the top and bottom cells will look just like the cells in the middle with no top and bottom corners.  How can I set the background so that the top and bottom cells are rounded without ending up having each cells look the same. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Also another side note. There are cases where the tableview cell only display one cell, which means that every corner are rounded. So how do you set the background that can handle all these cases.

Comment: do you want to change background view or color?

Comment: not the color i think.  Because I'm trying to add a gradient background.

Comment: Try cell.backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set background gradient for cells, in this case you may don't worry about rounded corners because you use cell.layer. (for this import Quartz framework in your project)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) 
     {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            if (indexPath.row == 0)  // first cell
            {
         // set background gradient
         CAGradientLayer *gradient =  [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
         gradient.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
         gradient.frame = cell.frame; 
         gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.207 green:0.207 blue:0.207 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.125 green:0.125 blue:0.125 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
             [[cell.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
         [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
         [gradient release];
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 1) // second cell
            {
            //
            // Another gradient
            //
            }
      }
      return cell;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"Here my first cell");
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myFirstCellPicture.png"]];
     } else {
        NSLog(@"myOtherCells");
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"otherCellPicture.PNG"]];

    }

}
```